# Ajax not sending request

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have been struggling on this simple problem for pretty long already, yes I tried to google for answer though with no luck, the problem is that my ajax request doesn't even send a thing, so I guess it has something to do with the syntax though it looks perfectly fine to me:

```
$(window).on('load',function()
{
    $("#unfriend_user > p").click(function()
    {
        $.ajax(
        {
            url: "php_includes/remove_friend.php", 
            type: "POST",
            data: 
            {
                user_1 : <?php echo $logged_id ?> ,
                user_2 : <?php echo $page_user_id ?>,
                user_username : <?php echo $logged_username ?>,
                user_password : <?php echo $logged_password ?>
            },
            success: function(data)
            {
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

All php  echoed variables have values.

The problem came up after I added these two lines:

```
user_username : <?php echo $logged_username ?>,
user_password : <?php echo $logged_password ?>
```

If I remove these two lines and "," everything works just fine.

Comment: The values of `$logged_username` and/or `$logged_password` are probably breaking the JavaScript in the client, thus stopping the ajax call from ever happening. Check your debug console in your browser for any errors.

Comment: I just realised theses are strings not numbers so they need '' ......... JESUS CHRIST I've been looking for problem for so long...

Comment: There's also a very good chance you're doing something wrong if you're dumping a password in plain-text into your page. Take a look at the API of whatever it is you're doing, and look for token-based authentication or something that wouldn't require you to keep any plaintext passwords.

Comment: You shouldn't have access to the plain text password in the first place (although I'm not saying you do). If you are storing passwords, make sure you hash them somehow before storage.

Comment: Don't worry, it's hashed...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at your rendered HTML ("View Source" in the browser), you'll see that your javascript looks something like:

```
data: 
    {
        user_1 : 1 ,
        user_2 : 2,
        user_username : someusername,
        user_password : somepassword
   },
```

Since those are strings (I'm assuming), you need to quote them:

```
data: 
    {
        user_1 : <?php echo $logged_id ?> ,
        user_2 : <?php echo $page_user_id ?>,
        user_username : "<?php echo $logged_username ?>",
        user_password : "<?php echo $logged_password ?>"
    },
```

Comment: Yep that was the problem, I'll accept your answer in a couple of minutes, sometimes I wonder how I am even allowed to code when I'm making mistake like these...

Answer (score 1):

probably you are braking javascript syntax
since username and password are strings you need to quote them

best way will be to use [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

json_encode will put quote when needed

```
$(window).on('load',function()
{
    $("#unfriend_user > p").click(function()
    {
        $.ajax(
        {
            url: "php_includes/remove_friend.php", 
            type: "POST",
            data: 
            {
                user_1 : <?php echo json_encode($logged_id) ?> ,
                user_2 : <?php echo json_encode($page_user_id) ?>,
                user_username : <?php echo json_encode($logged_username) ?>,
                user_password : <?php echo json_encode($logged_password) ?>
            },
            success: function(data)
            {
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```